# Weighted Average in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two RDDs, the first I'll call `userVisits` that looks like this:

```
((123, someurl,Mon Nov 04 00:00:00 PST 2013),11.0)
```

and the second is allVisits:

```
((someurl,Mon Nov 04 00:00:00 PST 2013),1122.0)
```

I can do `userVisits.reduceByKey(_+_)` can get the number of visits by that user.  I can do allVisits and get the same.  What I want to do is get a weighted average for the users dividing the users visits by the total visits for the day.  I need to lookup a value in allVisits with part of the key tuple in user visits.  I'm guessing it could be done with a map like this:

```
userVisits.reduceByKey(_+_).map( item => item._2 / allVisits.get(item._1))
```

I know **allVisits.get(key)** doesn't exist, but how could I accomplish something like that?

The alternative is getting the keys from allVisits and mapping each number of keys from userVisits then joining the two, but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only universal option I see here is `join`:

```
val userVisitsAgg = userVisits.reduceByKey(_ + _)
val allVisitsAgg = allVisits.reduceByKey(_ + _)

userVisitsAgg.map{case ((id, url, date), sum) => ((url, date), (id, sum))}
  .join(allVisitsAgg)
  .map{case ((url, date), ((id, userSum), (urlSum))) => 
    ((id, url, date), userSum / urlSum)}
```

If `allVisitsAgg` is small enough to be broadcasted you can simplify above to something like this:

```
val allVisitsAggBD = sc.broadcast(allVisitsAgg.collectAsMap)
userVisitsAgg.map{case ((id, url, date), sum) =>
  ((id, url), sum / allVisitsAggBD.value((url, date)))
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you're willing to switch to `DataFrames` you can simplify this a little but it shouldn't be a huge difference.