# Weighted average with Spark Datasets without UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

While someone has already asked about computing a [Weighted Average in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34325152/weighted-average-in-spark), in this question, I'm asking about using Datasets/DataFrames instead of RDDs.

How do I compute a weighted average in Spark?  I have two columns: counts and previous averages:

```
case class Stat(name:String, count: Int, average: Double)
val statset = spark.createDataset(Seq(Stat("NY", 1,5.0),
                           Stat("NY",2,1.5),
                           Stat("LA",12,1.0),
                           Stat("LA",15,3.0)))
```

I would like to be able to compute a weighted average like this:

```
display(statset.groupBy($"name").agg(sum($"count").as("count"),
                    weightedAverage($"count",$"average").as("average")))
```

One can use a UDF to get close:

```
val weightedAverage = udf(
  (row:Row)=>{
    val counts = row.getAs[WrappedArray[Int]](0)
    val averages = row.getAs[WrappedArray[Double]](1)
    val (count,total) = (counts zip averages).foldLeft((0,0.0)){
      case((cumcount:Int,cumtotal:Double),(newcount:Int,newaverage:Double))=>(cumcount+newcount,cumtotal+newcount*newaverage)}
    (total/count)  // Tested by returning count here and then extracting. Got same result as sum.
  }
)

display(statset.groupBy($"name").agg(sum($"count").as("count"),
                    weightedAverage(struct(collect_list($"count"),
                                    collect_list($"average"))).as("average")))
```

(Thanks to answers to [Passing a list of tuples as a parameter to a spark udf in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551410/passing-a-list-of-tuples-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-udf-in-scala) for help in writing this)

Newbies: Use these imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this with built-in column functions instead of UDFs? The UDF feels clunky and if the numbers get large you have to convert the Int's to Long's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you could do it in two passes:

```
val totalCount = statset.select(sum($"count")).collect.head.getLong(0)

statset.select(lit(totalCount) as "count", sum($"average" * $"count" / lit(totalCount)) as "average").show
```

Or, including the groupBy you just added:

```
display(statset.groupBy($"name").agg(sum($"count").as("count"),
                    sum($"count"*$"average").as("total"))
               .select($"name",$"count",($"total"/$"count")))
```

Comment: I would add the total count as another column  in the second aggregation and then do the division on the end. The second pass would need to go over much less data.

Comment: @MichelLemay: Thanks! That's just what I needed to jog my thinking. I've suggested an edit to your answer that also works with groupBy.

Comment: you can accept the answer @JosiahYoder if it helped you